# How to disable on load scale animation on Vuetify

Tags: animation, loading, vuetify.js

I have installed Vuetify on my app using https://github.com/nuxt-community/create-nuxt-app generator.
The problem is there is a scale animation on first load of page. Something like that page is half scale and goes to 100% scale smoothly. I want to disable it!!

Comment: that certainly not standard behaviour and noone going to help u without a reproducible code

Comment: how can I disable it?